# How to be a better magento 2 developer

Tags: magento2, learn-magento

(I know this is not a programming question but don't know where else to put it )

I come from been a **magento 1** junior developer for maybe a couple of months, then **M2** hit and we are focusing more on M2, I have learned magento(and also you might have) by having a specific situation and google about it but I want to go even a bit deeper.

Can anyone advice me how to become a better **magento 2 developer** ? for now I want to focus on backend situation, any books , sites will be good.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn, debug, practice. take a course from magento if possible, read devdocs, Pass some time stackexchage...

Comment: Totally agree with @SohelRana :)

Comment: Read necessarily https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/

Comment: If you work your way through the Magento Certified Professional Developer study guide and practice the techniques on a vanilla M2 site, you'll be in a really good position. Also, Alan Storm has a fantastic tutorial series for M2. Examples accompanied by explanation, priceless.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would be useful.

For Magento 2 Developer Documentation

> https://devdocs.magento.com

For Magento 2 Video tutorial

> https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/

Other tutorials:

> https://www.toptal.com/magento/magento-2-tutorial-building-a-complete-module
>
> https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/